# Как в Unity 5 делать сборки обновлений для Google Play?

Tags: unity3d, google-play, обновления

Сделал игру на Unity 5, загрузил в Google Play, потом возникла необходимость сделать обновление, пофиксить парочку багов. Но когда залил проект, и обновление опубликовалось, оно весит, как и целая игра. Как реализовать обновления?

Comment: А разве через Google Play бывают частичные обновления? Из Google Play всегда полностью установка идёт. Если хотите, можете сделать свою модульную систему - докачку контента уже из самого приложения после обновления через Google Play основного модуля.

Answer (score -1):

Вот вам [Руководство от Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=ru).

**Подготовка APK**

Прежде чем публиковать обновление, проверьте, соблюдаются ли все перечисленные ниже условия.

Название пакета приложения обновленного APK и текущей версии совпадают.
Значение кода версии больше номера текущей версии.
Подписи обновленного APK и текущей версии совпадают.
Чтобы проверить, используется ли в старой и новой версиях один и тот же сертификат, выполните в обоих APK следующую команду и сравните результаты:

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

Если результаты совпадают, то используется один и тот же ключ и можно продолжать. В противном случае необходимо подписать APK с помощью правильного ключа.

**Доставка обновлений**

После загрузки обновления для приложения вы будете видеть статус "Ожидание обновления" в правой верхней части любой страницы консоли разработчика, пока оно не будет опубликовано. После публикации приложение начнет обновляться у существующих пользователей, и этот статус исчезнет.

Comment: и как это может помочь ответить на вопрос? Выделите главное тогда отсюда.